# How can I position a generated element beside the original button/link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I would like to show the three social elements generated by the "social" link on the left of the same "social" link after clicking on it.

So, I would like to get this IN THE SAME LINE like after clicking on "social":

FACEBOOK TWITTER EMAIL SOCIAL

Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-social-1", this).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
a.trigger {
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.subicons
 {
    display:none;
}

li.list{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show/hide on click:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="icon icon-social icon-social-1"><i>Social</i></a>
            <ul class="subicons">
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">e-mail</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the problem? style the way you want

Comment: Seems to be working here. We don't understand the problem. Just change the position of the elements if the problem is that they're to the right instead of to the left of the social link.

Comment: I don't know how to position them on the left of "social". I'd like to get this:
FACEBOOK   TWITTER   EMAIL   SOCIAL   in the same line

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `toggle()` function show element with the CSS `display: block` property, which will not achieve what you want. Use the `css()` function or `toggleClass()` function instead.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(this).siblings(".subicons").toggleClass('hide');
```

**CSS:**

```
.subicons{
  display:inline;
  padding-left:0;
}
.subicons.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-social-1", this).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
a.trigger {
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.subicons
 {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:0;
}
.subicons.hide
 {
    display:none;
}

li.list{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show/hide on click:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul class="subicons hide">
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Facebook</a></li>
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">e-mail</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="" class="icon icon-social icon-social-1"><i>Social</i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".icon-social-1", this).on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
a.trigger {
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.subicons
 { 
    display:inline-block;
    
}

li.list{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show/hide on click:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
   
            <a href="" class="icon icon-social icon-social-1"><i>Social:</i></a>
            <div class="subicons" style="display:none">
             
               <a href="" target="_blank" class="">Facebook</a>
               <a href="" target="_blank" class="">Twitter</a>
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="">e-mail</a>
            </div>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.subicons {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

I think he wants to remove the padding caused by ul tag. UL tags have padding left by default.

Comment: Hi Kushtrim, thank you for your help :)
I've tried to update my question, because I don't mind about the padding

Comment: Use "toggleClass()" instead of "toggle()". And your class should have .yourClass{ display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

```
.subicons {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

The above code will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just move sublist before the hyperlink so they're in the correct order already and then set `display: inline-block` on the subicons list.

```
.subicons {
    display: inline-block;
}

<li>
    <ul class="subicons">
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">e-mail</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="" class="icon icon-social icon-social-1"><i>Social</i></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Almost. Have a look at Ryan';s answer as well. The issue is that `.toggle()` swicthes between display none and display inline instead of display none and display inline-block. SO you just need to change the onlick function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the order of the html and want the "social" link to stay in one place you can use absolute positioning for the social links. Ensure there's a parent that's positioned, in this case I chose `.socials`. Also, `a.trigger` wasn't doing anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".icon-social-1", this).on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".subicons").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a.icon {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 170px;
}

.socials {
  position: relative;
}

ul.subicons {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

li.list {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show/hide on click:</strong></p>
<div class="socials click">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="icon icon-social icon-social-1"><i>Social</i></a>
      <ul class="subicons">
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="" target="_blank" class="">e-mail</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```